# Java: JTextField autoselect text after show frame

Tags: jtextfield

I have JTextField.
**txtPickANick.setText("Pick a nick name");** 
and I need select text when show JFrame with this Text.
I try selectAll() but its not working.

```
private JTextField getTxtPickANick() {
    if (txtPickANick == null) {
        txtPickANick = new JTextField();
        txtPickANick.setFont(new Font("Bookman Old Style", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        txtPickANick.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);             
        txtPickANick.setBounds(44, 74, 185, 21);
        txtPickANick.setColumns(10);
        txtPickANick.setDocument(new LimitDlzka(17));
        txtPickANick.setText("Pick a nick name");
        txtPickANick.selectAll();


    }
    return txtPickANick;
}
```

Comment: In declaration JtexField, I editet my post.

Comment: Can't replicate this. Could be an issue with your `LimitDlzka` document but cannot see the code for that

Answer (score 0):

Calling `selectAll()` after displaying the frame works - not sure what the earliest point where you can call it is though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textPickANic.requestFocus();` to focus it. And after that you can apply `selectAll();` method.